# How do you pronounce Micropterus?

Tags: biology, fishing

How do you pronounce Micropterus, a genus for a fish.

Comment: This is off-topic for this site. Also, this is relatively hard to answer in written form. Maybe ask someone in real life?

Comment: You can google this. Just type in "Micropterus pronunciation" and you'll probably get a video of someone saying it aloud for you.

Comment: [Here is a video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HG1tNQggSRg) of someone pronouncing it. There are lots of pronunciation videos on YouTube, and lots of dictionary pages will speak the word aloud if you click the little icon of a speaker next to the word. On [this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Micropterus) the icon has a flag with it, showing both American and British pronunciations.

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of pronunciation videos on YouTube, like [this one](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HG1tNQggSRg), and lots of dictionary pages will speak the word aloud if you click the little icon of a speaker next to the word, like on [this page](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/Micropterus):

[image]

[On this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Micropterus) the icon has a flag with it, showing both American and British pronunciations:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. The driveby downvoter, as always, struck with no apparent reason - while the question is off topic the answer suits it perfectly so as to still help the asker.

Comment: @Zxyrra Lots of people feel that posting answers to obviously off-topic questions encourages more off-topic questions. As such, while the answer may technically be valid and useful, even correct, given the question, its existence encourages the wrong behavior on the part of the person who asked the question in the first place. That may very well be the reason for the downvote on the answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Oh! I didn't know that. Thanks for explaining. I can delete my answer if that'd be better.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Ah, I see. It is most polite for the downvoter to tell Thom this information, but thank you for doing so.